# Is there any difference between push_back() and resize(size()+1)

Tags: c++, stdvector

A standard vector can be expanded to hold one more member by doing either:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
```

or

```
int os = v.size();
v.resize(os+1);
v[os] = 1;
```

Apart from the terseness of the code using push_back(), are there any other differences? For example, is one more efficient than the other, or is the extra memory assigned differently in each case?

Comment: They're different functions designed for different purposes. Comparing them for "speed" isn't useful.

Comment: `push_back` isn't terse; `resize` is verbose!

Comment: @meagar - but do they expand memory in the same way?

Comment: This thread may be useful to answer your question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902832/resize-versus-push-back-in-stdvector-does-it-avoid-an-unnecessary-copy-assig>

Comment: If your *screw* is appending, `push_back` is a screwdriver, and `resize(size()+1) + assignment` is a hammer. You might get the screw in, but it is clearly now what the tool was designed for.

Comment: @AndrewS. Why don't you just look at the code of push_back to see if there's a difference?

Answer (score 8):

`push_back` will construct in-place, meaning it calls the copy constructor.

`resize` will call the default constructor, and then `v[os]` will call the assignment operator.

Use `push_back`.

---

As Lightness says, the allocations in either case are equivalent. See his answer for more details.

Here's an example: http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=43766666e5c72d282bd94c05e43e8897

Comment: +1 if you include the fact that the memory allocations in either case should be completely equivalent.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is that a requirement of the standard? I thought `push_back` tends to reserve more than it needs.

Comment: Thanks - that was the distinction I was looking for

Comment: I thought `push_back` only allocated the memory when growing, but `resize` allocated memory and then default initialized it.

Comment: @Pubby: No more or less so than `resize`

Comment: @Marlon: Yes, that is the case.

Comment: http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=43766666e5c72d282bd94c05e43e8897

Comment: 1. IIRC in C++03 the compiler is free to NOT call copy constructor and just  construct in-place so it is not as sub-optimal as it looks like (assuming you compile with optimization enabled). 2. In C++0x `push_back` would call move constructor instead of copy.

Answer (score 5):

#### Memory expansion

> but do they expand memory in the same way?

It is not specified explicitly in C++11 (I checked), but **yes**.

`resize` in this case is defined to "append to the container", the only logical interpretation of which makes it equivalent to `insert` and `push_back` in terms of allocation.

The back-end of the container implementation usually allocates "more than it needs" in all cases when its memory block is expanded — this is done by the standard *not prohibiting it* rather than the standard mandating it, and there is no wording to suggest that this is not the case for `resize` also.

Ultimately, then, it's completely up to the implementation, but I'd be surprised to see a difference in memory allocation rules between the two approaches on any mainstream compiler.

[This testcase](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=43766666e5c72d282bd94c05e43e8897) shows one simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a, b;

    for(int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
      a.push_back(0);
    for(int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
      b.resize(i+1);

    std::cout << a.capacity() << " , " << b.capacity() << std::endl;
}

// Output from my GCC 4.7.2:
//  128 , 128
```

Note that [this one](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=145e5f6821da7f0e97e5ccb4fd13193c) is subtly different:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> a, b;

    for(int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
      a.push_back(0);
    b.resize(100);

    std::cout << a.capacity() << " , " << b.capacity() << std::endl;
}

// Output from my GCC 4.7.2:
//  128 , 100
```

This is *not a fair test* between the two approaches, because in the latter example we're expanding memory in different increments, and the memory backing sequence containers tends to be expanded in *multiples*.

---

#### Performance concerns

Anyway, as @Pubby identifies, in the `resize` case you'll do the implicit construction followed by the explicit assignment, which is non-optimal if you're prematurely optimising.

In the real world, the real issue here is *using the wrong function for the job* and *writing silly code*.

Answer (score 3):

They are not comparable, and you should not base the decision on performance, but that being said the performance might differ quite a lot depending on the implementation.

The standard requires `push_back()` to have amortized constant time, which basically means that the implementation must grow the buffer for the objects following a geometric series (i.e. when growing, the new size must be proportional to the previous size by a factor F > 1).

There is no such requirement for `resize()`. As a matter of fact some implementations assume that if you are calling `resize()` it is because you have better knowledge of what the final size of the vector will be. With that in mind, those implementations will grow the buffer (if needed) to exactly the size that you are requesting, not following a geometric progression. That means that the cost of appending following this mechanism can be O(N^2), instead of O(N) for the `push_back` case.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there can be a significant difference, particularly when using custom data types. Observe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct S
{
    S()
    {
        std::cout << "S()\n";
    }

    S(const S&)
    {
        std::cout << "S(const S&)\n";
    }

    S& operator = (const S&)
    {
        std::cout << "operator =\n";
        return *this;
    }

    ~S()
    {
        std::cout << "~S()\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> v1;

    std::cout << "push_back:\n";
    v1.push_back(S());

    std::vector<S> v2;

    std::cout << '\n' << "resize:\n";
    v2.resize(1);
    v2[0] = S();

    std::cout << "\nend\n"; // Ignore destructors after "end" (they're not pertinent to the comparison)
}
```

Output:

```
push_back:
S()
S(const S&)
~S()

resize:
S()
S(const S&)
~S()
S()
operator =
~S()

end
~S()
~S()
```

`push_back` FTW.

**Edit:** In response to @Lightness Races in Orbit's comment, this is, of course, just a silly example. `S` obviously isn't a really "useful" `struct`, and if you remove all the printing statements, or simply define `S` as `struct S {};`, then of course the compiler can optimize a lot of it away.

**But** since when do you *only* use incredibly trivial data types in a program? You'll use some trivial data types, but you'll also likely use some non-trivial data types someday too. These non-trivial data types may have expensive constructors, destructors, or assignment operators (or they may not be super expensive, but they may add up if you repeatedly use `resize` instead of `push_back`), and `push_back` would certainly be the right choice.

Comment: Is this really _significant_? Those calls are going to be optimised out when you remove the `std::cout` lines.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The point is, though, that if you have some data type with non-trivial constructors, assignment operators, or destructors that you will have to pay for that. Of course trivial things don't matter that much (like the `int` example in the question); for non-trivial data types, however, it can add up.

Comment: I'm not going to suggest that anyone use `resize`+assignment over `push_back`, of course; I'm just not going to accept that it's going to be anywhere near the bottleneck in any more than 1% of cases :)

Answer (score 0):

`resize()` may allocate memory better when you need to add add few elements.

i.e

```
std::vector<int> v;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    v.push_back(1);
or

int os = v.size();
v.resize(os.size() + n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    v[os + i] = 1;
```

But in this case it's better to use

```
v.reserve(os.size() + n);
```

and then push_back's, it'll avoid construction + assignment too, as in your case